# Using Selenium to manage Fidelity website. Can't log out using Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I have been able to to get selenium to login. But I habe trouble trying to log out.  Usually there is an id to reference, but in thics case there is not. The HTML snippet of code from Fidelity's website is

```
  <li class="pnls last-child">
            <a href="https://login.fidelity.com/ftgw/Fidelity/RtlCust/Logout/Init?AuthRedUrl=https://www.fidelity.com/customer-service/customer-logout"
 target="_top">Log Out</a>
   </li>
```

I tried to use

```
  search_input = driver.find_element_by_class_name('pnls last-child')
```

but got the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".pnls last-child"}
```

I also tried to use

```
search_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.pnls last-child')
```

but got the error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"li.pnls last-child"}
```

Finally, I tried

```
 search_input = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Log Out")
```

and got the error message

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Log Out"}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try these options. I think all of them should work:

```py
search_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.pnls.last-child')
```

or

```py
search_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.pnls.last-child a')
```

or

```py
search_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Log Out')]")
```

or

```py
search_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'customer-logout')]")
```

or

```py
search_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='pnls last-child']//a[contains(@href,'customer-logout')]")
```

In case you are getting `element not interactable` error try adding explicit wait as following:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,'customer-logout')]"))).click()
```

or

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.pnls last-child"))).click()
```

To use `WebDriverWait` you will have to import these imports:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Alternatively (but less recommended) to using the `WebDriverWait` if the above still not working you can use JavaScript executor click as following:

```py
logout = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'customer-logout')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", logout)
```

You can use all the other suggested locators here as well

Comment: Hi. Thanks for trying but you struck out on all variations that you provided.  Here are your suggestions followed by the error messages

Comment: I was not able to finish the last comment. So to repeat with more info., The xpath ones usually gave the message "is not a valid XPath expression." while the css_selector gave ": Message: element not interactable"

Comment: Please see my updated answer. XPaths are fixed as well.

Comment: Thanks. In regards to the three additional examples the first and third ones work, but the second one does not.

Comment: So, I gave you at least 2 working solutions. Why don't you accept my answer?

Comment: oh Sorry. I will do that.  You do deserve credit. Hopefully the next reader will read the comments and realize that some suggestions worked and others did not.

Comment: These are only locators, for each other web page they obviously will be different. It's only knowledge to create good locators and give a delay to make the element visible / clickable.